# Does anyone know how to alter function so that only the generated list is output to csv, without every other row in df being split by number in range?

Tags: python, pandas, list

```
clip1=[1,3,4,5,6,7]
clip2=[8,10,11,12,13]
clip3=[15,16,18,19,20]
cut=[]

def toe_clip(clip1, clip2, clip3):
    a= random.choice(clip1)
    b= random.choice(clip2)
    c= random.choice(clip3)
    cut.append([a,b,c])
    return 

for i in range(200):
    toe_clip(clip1,clip2,clip3)
    cut.append(i)

print(cut)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Toe_clip_ID": cut})
df.to_csv("toe_clip2.csv", sep=',',index=False)
```

I'm trying to create a list of randomly generated number combinations. The combinations have to have 3 numbers. The first number needs to be from in the `clip1` list. The second number from the `clip2` list, etc. Also the combinations generated have to be unique. No combinations can be used multiple times.

I'm trying to save the generated `cut` list to a csv file. With the code shown, the output is separated by the numbers in  `range(200)` with the combination and number of range alternating every other row. Does anyone know how to just get the generated cut combination list to print, without the corresponding 0-199 numbers? I've copied below the beginning of the output you get when you print the current `cut`list.

[[6, 11, 18], 0, [4, 13, 19], 1, [3, 12, 15], 2, [3, 12, 20], 3, [3, 8, 18], 4, [3, 10, 16], 5, [6, 8, 18], 6, [3, 11, 20], 7, [5, 10, 18], 8, [4, 8, 18], 9, [7, 8, 19], 10, [1, 12, 19], 11, [7, 12, 18], 12, [7, 10, 18], 13, [5, 10, 18], 14, [7, 11, 15], 15, [4, 12, 16],

Comment: What does *"without every other row in df being split by number in range"* mean?

Comment: if I understood your problem correct,  you could remove the "cut.append(i)" and you will accomplish what you want

Comment: Wow, that was a silly mistake on my end! Thank you T. Novais! Removing that line of code fixed the issue. Thanks -Lauren

Comment: Does anyone know how to alter the code so that only unique 3-digit combinations are generated? I thought I wasn't getting the replicate combos in the ```cut``` list, but I just realized that is false

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
clip1=[1,3,4,5,6,7]
clip2=[8,10,11,12,13]
clip3=[15,16,18,19,20]
from itertools import product
cut = [list(i) for i in product(clip1, clip2, clip3)]
print(cut)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 8, 15], [1, 8, 16], [1, 8, 18], [1, 8, 19], [1, 8, 20], [1, 10, 15], [1, 10, 16], [1, 10, 18], [1, 10, 19], [1, 10, 20], [1, 11, 15], [1, 11, 16], [1, 11, 18], [1, 11, 19], [1, 11, 20], [1, 12, 15], [1, 12, 16], [1, 12, 18], [1, 12, 19], [1, 12, 20], [1, 13, 15], [1, 13, 16], [1, 13, 18], [1, 13, 19], [1, 13, 20], [3, 8, 15], [3, 8, 16], [3, 8, 18], [3, 8, 19], [3, 8, 20], [3, 10, 15], [3, 10, 16], [3, 10, 18], [3, 10, 19], [3, 10, 20], [3, 11, 15], [3, 11, 16], [3, 11, 18], [3, 11, 19], [3, 11, 20], [3, 12, 15], [3, 12, 16], [3, 12, 18], [3, 12, 19], [3, 12, 20], [3, 13, 15], [3, 13, 16], [3, 13, 18], [3, 13, 19], [3, 13, 20], [4, 8, 15], [4, 8, 16], [4, 8, 18], [4, 8, 19], [4, 8, 20], [4, 10, 15], [4, 10, 16], [4, 10, 18], [4, 10, 19], [4, 10, 20], [4, 11, 15], [4, 11, 16], [4, 11, 18], [4, 11, 19], [4, 11, 20], [4, 12, 15], [4, 12, 16], [4, 12, 18], [4, 12, 19], [4, 12, 20], [4, 13, 15], [4, 13, 16], [4, 13, 18], [4, 13, 19], [4, 13, 20], [5, 8, 15], [5, 8, 16], [5, 8, 18], [5, 8, 19], [5, 8, 20], [5, 10, 15], [5, 10, 16], [5, 10, 18], [5, 10, 19], [5, 10, 20], [5, 11, 15], [5, 11, 16], [5, 11, 18], [5, 11, 19], [5, 11, 20], [5, 12, 15], [5, 12, 16], [5, 12, 18], [5, 12, 19], [5, 12, 20], [5, 13, 15], [5, 13, 16], [5, 13, 18], [5, 13, 19], [5, 13, 20], [6, 8, 15], [6, 8, 16], [6, 8, 18], [6, 8, 19], [6, 8, 20], [6, 10, 15], [6, 10, 16], [6, 10, 18], [6, 10, 19], [6, 10, 20], [6, 11, 15], [6, 11, 16], [6, 11, 18], [6, 11, 19], [6, 11, 20], [6, 12, 15], [6, 12, 16], [6, 12, 18], [6, 12, 19], [6, 12, 20], [6, 13, 15], [6, 13, 16], [6, 13, 18], [6, 13, 19], [6, 13, 20], [7, 8, 15], [7, 8, 16], [7, 8, 18], [7, 8, 19], [7, 8, 20], [7, 10, 15], [7, 10, 16], [7, 10, 18], [7, 10, 19], [7, 10, 20], [7, 11, 15], [7, 11, 16], [7, 11, 18], [7, 11, 19], [7, 11, 20], [7, 12, 15], [7, 12, 16], [7, 12, 18], [7, 12, 19], [7, 12, 20], [7, 13, 15], [7, 13, 16], [7, 13, 18], [7, 13, 19], [7, 13, 20]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
clip1=[1,3,4,5,6,7]
clip2=[8,10,11,12,13]
clip3=[15,16,18,19,20]
cut=[]
for x in clip1:
    for y in clip2:
        for z in clip3:        
            cut.append([x,y,z])
 
print(cut)
print(len(cut))
```

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly the code and output I was trying to get! Thank you